# Image is null after creation with not null InputStream

Tags: java, inputstream, bufferedimage

I have the following code:

```
public BufferedImage inputStreamToImage (InputStream stream) {        

    BufferedImage image = null;

    if (stream != null ) {

        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(stream);
            // image is still null here <--
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    return image;
}
```

I test if the InputStream is null, which it's not. I then create a new BufferedImage from the InputStream. Again nothing goes wrong and code executes like it's working. But then when I try and use the image it's null.. In other words, right after a "successful" creation I test the image and it's null.

**EDIT**

I upload a .tif file via a html form like so:

```
<form action="webresources/read" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <p>
    Select a file : <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    </p>

    <input type="submit" value="Upload It" />

</form>
```

Any help? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.InputStream%29):

> If no registered ImageReader claims to be able to read the resulting stream, null is returned.

You `InputStream` probably does not **exactly** contain a readable image.

Comment: That's really weird, I upload a .tif file from a html web form though (please see updated question). Are tif files not supported then maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Ah! So.. The reason is that ImageIO.read() does not support .tif images. I tried it with a .jpg and it worked fine.

Comment: Any format is "supported". However, only JPEG, PNG, BMP, WBMP and GIF support is bundled with the JRE. To read TIFF, install a plugin, like the one from JAI ImageIO or other 3rd party plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to have the following case stated in the documentation of ImageIO - "The InputStream is wrapped in an ImageInputStream. If no registered ImageReader claims to be able to read the resulting stream, null is returned."?

Comment: A question is not an answer.

Comment: I cannot solve a problem when I don't have the code. That was a suggestion.